# Difference between pointer-events and cursor

Tags: css, hover

I recently came across `pointer-events` as a way to turn off the mouse changing on hover. I've always used `cursor` to disable this change.

So what's the difference between `pointer-events` and `cursor`?

Comment: The first controls function while the latter controls appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pointer-events` property gives control over how an element can respond to touch or click events, while the `cursor` property just controls what the cursor should look like in that event.

i.e. `cursor: pointer` will show a pointer finger when you hover over the element... `cursor: disabled` will show a cross sign showing the element might be disabled.

`pointer-events: none` on the other hand, will make the element completely unresponsive to a hover or click.

CSS-tricks has a write up here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: So should `pointer-events` be used instead of `event.preventDefault`? Or should I use both to doubly ensure that things don't happen when clicked?

Comment: I wouldn't say one should be used in place of the other - both have useful purposes. Plus preventDefault should still allow things like :hover, I believe (someone may want to clarify that however)